# Erro ao tentar salvar log de repositório git em arquivo txt (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, git, txt

Olá,
Estou tentando escrever um código em Python para salvar um git log de um repositório git em um arquivo .txt em um diretório diferente usando a função `subprocess.Popen()`. Sei que a sintaxe para usar na linha de comando é:

`git -C [diretorioGit] log --first-parent --pretty="%H" > [diretorio/arquivoDestino]`

porém ao tentar fazer usando a função em Python:

`subprocess.Popen(["git", "-C", "github_repos/ChainLink-Token", "log", "--first-parent", "--pretty="+ "%H", '>' ,"../../github_commits/ChainLink-Token_commits.txt"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()`

o seguinte erro aparece:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '>': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

alguém saberia dizer qual o erro?

Obs: por a linha de comando está funcionando

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Tenta `'--pretty="%H"'` .

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar amigo, mas não funcionou

Comment: Se o comando funciona interativamente, certamente o problema gira em torno dessas aspas do %H, porque da forma que está na pergunta está claramente errado (as aspas não vão fazer parte do comando invocado pelo Popen()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma opção, é você executar apenas os comandos do git no `Popen` e com o retorno do método, escrever no arquivo:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["git", "-C", ".", "log", "--first-parent", '--pretty="%H"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

with open("ChainLink-Token_commits.txt", "w") as log:
    [log.write(data.decode("utf-8")) for data in proc if data]
```

Isso até da a possibilidade de alterar a forma que os dados são gravados no arquivo texto... Claro, se necessário.

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel